# How to use Cider's overlay

Tags: emacs, overlay, cider

I want to try Cider’s overlay option. I understand it looks like Lighttable’s  InstaRepl, without the instant evaluation. I cannot get it to work, though, for example M-x cider-use-overlays returns no match.

I am using cider/cider-nrepl 0.11.0 and cider 0.11.0

Here is my Cider config:

```
(use-package cider
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :config
  (setq nrepl-log-messages t
        cider-repl-display-in-current-window t
        cider-repl-use-clojure-font-lock t
        cider-prompt-save-file-on-load 'always-save
        cider-font-lock-dynamically '(macro core function var)
        nrepl-hide-special-buffers t
        cider-overlays-use-font-lock t)
  (cider-repl-toggle-pretty-printing))
```

What do I need to do to get this to work, please?
Also are there any good tutorials on Cider overlay?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cider-use-overlays` is a variable, not a function - you can't run a variable. There are many things in cider which are using overlays. This particular variable is enabled by default and controls the display of results (they were traditionally displayed in the minibuffer). There's also [enligten-mode](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider#enlighten-display-local-values), which was also inspired by LT.

Comment: Thank you, Bug! - enlighten-mode was what I was looking for.